# Auto-populate a column based on a different column

Tags: column, library

I was wondering if someone could help me with an issue I'm having in SharePoint.  I made a library and one of the columns has a Yes/No option.  The following column is based on that response.  If the answer is Yes I have a drop down with 3 different options, however if the answer is No there is only one option it could be.  Is it possible to have the column auto-populate is someone selects the No option?

Comment: I think the best way would be to add an If Then formula, I'm trying to say If [Systems Action Required] column is No, then [Systems Status] column should be N/A, if not then leave it blank.  I tried this:

=IF([Systems Action Required]="Yes",[Systems Status]="N/A",[Systems Status]="")

but it didn't work

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

I only know how to do this using InfoPath - create a rule pertaining to the yes/no column based on the value...populate the drop down according to the rule.
Hope this helps...